# how to "bind" users of my website to their "facebook" login ids?

Tags: api, facebook

I have a website and I want to accomplish the following:

1. my site's server is able to uniquely identify the viewer of the website (assuming he is currently logged in to FB). NOTE: I don't need any personal information. I just need to know that he is unique. So if he comes back again tomorrow, I'll know its him.
2. based on this unique identification, store data in my website's database about his actions (eg. he uploads something etc).
3. my site should also be able to know if he has "liked" an item on my website.

A) Is the above possible at all?

B) If Yes, is it also possible that my site doesn't use "facebook login" for my site, and still achieve items 1 to 3 above? My understanding is that users can "like" and "comment" (using the social plugins) without the need to explicitly "FB LOGIN" on my site.

Reason for my asking question B is that I want to make using my site as seamless as possible (ie. don't have to "ask" users to give app access to my site to their information)

Comment: "don't have to "ask" users to give app access to my site to their information" At least you're *honest* about what you're trying to do...not that it makes it any less shady.

Comment: Thanks... No "shady" intentions. I just want to replace my site's login system with FB. The storing of user "actions" in my site's DB is purely to retain the site's existing functionality for the user.

I just want to make it seamless for the user to transation to FB login instead.

Answer (score 0):

A) Yes

B) No, it is possible with the facebook API to add simplified user sign-in and registration. A user will still need to confirm/allow the link to be made.

You can find more info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Funny thing, StackOverflow uses several of these APIs for it's users...

Comment: Ok I've updated my wordpress blog to use FB login. As a first next step, I intend to store all logged in user FB likes, into a local database as well. So if a user FB likes something, a record will also be inserted into my DB. 

How should i start to go about doing this?

Appreciate any sort of guidance at all.. thanks :)